# Count based on the initial date for a cohort in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the number of free trials and subscriptions by free trial start date as part of cohort, I have the data like in the bellow table:

Table test_data

```
date         subscription   type         duration    subscriber_id   price
01/01/2019   monthly        free_trial   7 days      1               10.00
08/01/2019   monthly        paid         30 days     1               10.00
01/01/2019   monthly        free_trial   7 days      2               10.00
02/01/2019   monthly        free_trial   7 days      3               10.00
09/01/2019   monthly        paid         30 days     3               10.00
08/02/2019   monthly        paid         30 days     3               10.00
```

So the subscriber_id 1 has one free trial and one subscription from 01/01/2019, the subscriber_id 2 has only one free trial from the same date and the subscriber_id 3 has one free trial, one subscription and one renew that should not be included. I am trying to get something like this:

```
date          free_trials      subscription
01/01/2019    2                1
02/01/2019    1                1
```

But I am stuck on how to get the subscription count part.

I got the following so far:

```
SELECT 
   date, 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'free_trial' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS free_trials 
FROM test_data
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

Any help, comments or links to tutorials are appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can do a self join to get you most of the way there

```
select free_trial.date
, count(distinct free_trial.subscriber_id) as free_trial
, count(distinct paid.type) as subscription 
from test_data free_trial
left join test_data paid on free_trial.subscriber_id = paid.subscriber_id
                        and paid.type = 'paid'
where free_trial.type = 'free_trial'
group by free_trial.date
```

What I can't figure out is what is different about the "renewal" that would cause it to be excluded.

Comment: The case with user 3 is that he had a free trial then paid the subscription and then renewed it, therefore It is only one subscription paid twice. Other way to put it would be that I want to include only the first payments in the subscription collum

Comment: In that case, you can do `count(distinct paid.subscriber_id)` as the subscription count.  If you wanted the renewal to count as a separate subscription, then remove "distinct"

Answer (score 1):

So you want to know how many of those free trials led to a paid subscription? This is what I'm thinking:

```
with trials as (
    select
        subscriber_id,
        min(case when type = 'free_trial' then date end) as trial_date,
        max(distinct case when type = 'paid' then 1 else null end) as subscribed
    from test_data
    group by subscriber_id
    having count(case when type in 'free_trial' then 1 else null end) > 0 -- had free trial
)
select trial_date, count(*), sum(subscribed) as subscribers
from trials
group by trial_date;
```